# sort lines by second and minute

Tags: bash

I have a very long not sorted log file from many sources, that every line of it has the time it was written in it.
i want to sort the log by the time, the problem is there was no convention where to write the time in the line, so I don't have any pattern base on delimiter or location in the line that i can filter by.
the only thing i know, is the format of time which is: hh:mm:ss.
lines for example:

> filename time
>
> time
>
> filename date time
>
> filename exception date time
>
> ...

how can i sort the file using this format - even though I don't know exact location in the line?
i need to be able to sore it by hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: post the actual readable input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` to extract the time (formatted as **hh:mm:ss**), prepend it at the beginning of the line, then use this new field for sort, and then remove it again with cut, like that:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)/\2\t\1\2/' data|
sort -t: -k3,3|cut -f2-
```

(this will sort by seconds, change this to -k2,2 or -k1,1 to sort by minutes or hours instead)

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if it explained what sort of time formats it aims to recognise...

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a good point ! I've updated my post to mention the input time format. Thanks !